# Can we combine multiple jQuery setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, compression, combinations

I have this following jQuery code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ToDo1").removeClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
    $("#ToDo1").addClass("fa-check-square");
    $("li:first").html("<i class='fa-li fa fa-check-square' id = 'ToDo1'></i>Download Complete");
    $("#ToDo2").addClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ToDo2").removeClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
    $("#ToDo2").addClass("fa-check-square");
    $("#ToDo3").addClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ToDo3").removeClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
    $("#ToDo3").addClass("fa-check-square");
    $("#ToDo4").addClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ToDo4").removeClass("fa-spin fa-spinner");
    $("#ToDo4").addClass("fa-check-square");
}, 5550);
```

Is there a way to shorten it, or is this the only way to accomplish the tasks?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like:

```
var delays = [2000, 3000, 5000, 5500],
  $todos = $("#ToDo1, #ToDo2, #ToDo3, #ToDo4");

$.each(delays, function(i, delay) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      $todos.eq(i).toggleClass("fa-spin fa-spinner fa-check-square");
      $todos.eq(i + 1).addClass("fa-check-square");// will fail silently when it doesn't exist
    if (i === 0) {
      $("li:first").html("<i class='fa-li fa fa-check-square' id = 'ToDo1'></i>Download Complete");
    }
  }, delay);
});
```

Note you are duplicating ID's in the first one when you inject html